# How do I sort a group of names into nested lists by their last name and then their first name?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list , for example, groups = [James Scott','Mary Robinson','Willie Hayes','Katherine Davis','Chad Butler','Josephine Clark','Zachary Jack] and I have to sort them in nested lists by their last name so people with last name starting with 'A' will be in the first list, people with 'B' in the second list an so on. Then I have have to sort them by their first name

Comment: Please provide the code where you have tried to solve it. You could start with figuring out how to do an alphabetical sort in general. There's loads of documentation online to check how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them using the following code:

```
sorted(groups, key = lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()[::-1]))
```

Comment: I get the error that the 'list' object has no attribute split

Comment: can you past the full code?, i am assuming group is the same as in your question.